# JavaScript function not executing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, wamp

I have this code:

```
function changeLogo() { var changeLogo = $("#logo").css("z-index", "8"); }
function delay() { setTimeout("changeLogo()",470) };
```

which is executed at: `bodyonLoad="delay()"`

This works in all browsers - BUT - for some bizarre reason, in Google Chrome on my desktop the function will not load. I know it's not a Chrome problem (it works on my laptop on Chrome) and it can't be WAMP as it works in other browsers. Has anyone got any idea about why this may be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass reference of function changeLogo in setTimeout.

```
function changeLogo() {
     var changeLogo = $("#logo").css("z-index", "8");
}
function delay() {
    setTimeout(changeLogo, 470)
};
```

Suggestion: I suggest you don't use same variable name (changeLogo).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try putting in a script at the end of body like this

```
</body>
<script type="text/javascript>
    setTimeout("changeLogo()", 470);
</script>
```

or try using jquery

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
    setTimeout("changeLogo()", 470);
});
```